# Скачивание написанного файла из textarea

Tags: javascript

Я использую ace.js.У меня есть textarea для html.Когда я пишу в этом редакторе что-то, а потом качаю и открываю мне не воспроизводиться, что я написал, а пишут undefined.Почему?Помогите пожалуйста!

```js
var eh = ace.edit("htmlEditor");
eh.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
eh.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
document.getElementById('htmlEditor').style.fontSize = '15px';

eh.getSession().on('change', function() {
  update();
})

function update() {
  var res = document.getElementById('result').contentWindow.document;
  res.open();
  res.write(eh.getValue());
  res.close();
}
update();

function download() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("drop-download");
  if (dropDown.style.display == "none") {
    dropDown.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function downloadHtmlFile() {
  var textToWrite = document.getElementById("htmlEditor").value;
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "hhsh.html";

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  } else {
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
    // before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Oswald|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Yeseva+One&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#htmlEditor {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 43vh;
  width: 33.03%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#line {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -40% 0 0 31%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 501px;
}

#line2 {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -40% 33.3% 0 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 501px;
  float: right;
}

#line3 {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -40% 0% 0 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 501px;
  float: right;
}

#cssEditor {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 43vh;
  width: 33.03%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#jsEditor {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 43vh;
  width: 33.03%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#result {
  min-height: 440px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 79.6%;
}

#line4 {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -26.8% 0% 0 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 414.5px;
  float: right;
}

#result-block {
  margin-top: -0.2%;
}

#title-of-textarea {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  background-color: #272822;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
}

#title-Html {
  padding: 0 0 0 1%;
  display: flex;
}

#title-css {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 2%;
  display: flex;
}

#title-js {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 2.5%;
  display: flex;
}

.mnu-code {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 2%;
}

.mnu-code li {
  padding-left: 5%;
}

#menu-code {
  width: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Arsenal', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#mnu-code {
  padding: 24% 0% 0 3%;
}

#drop-download {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  cursor: default;
}

#download-html::before {
  content: "\f13b";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#download-html {
  padding: 0% 0 0 5%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
}

#header-code {
  padding: 1% 0 1% 0;
  background-color: #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
}

#set {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#aside-block {
  width: 20%;
  height: 946px;
  background-color: #3b3d34;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content p {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.box-label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.save::before {
  content: "\f0c7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.download::before {
  content: "\f019";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#dropbtn-html {
  background-color: #272822;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
}

#dropbtn-css {
  background-color: #272822;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
}

.center-on-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0 !important;
  background-image: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

.select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2em;
  background: #2c3e50;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: .25em;
  margin: 1% 0% 5% 0;
  border: 1px solid #272822;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}


/* Arrow */

.select::after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  background: rgb(59, 61, 52);
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 2.4;
  -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
  -o-transition: .25s all ease;
  transition: .25s all ease;
  color: white;
}


/* Transition */

.select:hover::after {
  color: #f39c12;
}

#dropbtn {
  background-color: #272822;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 9000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 280%;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.language {
  padding: 6% 0 0 8%;
}

.dropdown-content #name-of-select1 {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content #name-of-select2 {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content-css {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9000;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 8%;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content-html {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9000;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 8%;
  display: none;
}

#title-js::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 4%;
  top: 5%;
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}

#title-css #dropbtn-css::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  left: 9%;
}

#title-Html #dropbtn-html::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  left: 9%;
}

.run-code::before {
  content: "\f144";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.change::before {
  content: "\f17a";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.box-text:before {
  content: "\f096";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#checkbox:checked+.box-text:before {
  content: "\f14a";
  color: #1e88e5;
  animation: checkanimate 200ms;
}

.box-label input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes checkanimate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal:400,400i&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js"></script>

<div id="aside-block">
  <div id="mnu-code">
    <label class="box-label">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked="" onclick="showTheme()">
  <span class="box-text">Темная тема</span>
 </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="header-code">
  <div id="menu-code">
    <ul class="mnu-code">
      <li class="run-code"> Проиграть</li>
      <li class="save"> Сохранить</li>
      <li class="change"> Поменять вид</li>
      <li class="download" onclick="download()">Скачать
        <div id="drop-download">
          <a id="download-html" onclick="downloadHtmlFile()">Скачать файл Html</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="htmlEditor"></div>
<div id="result-block">
  <iframe id="result" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div id="line4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, быстрее и лучше было бы вам почитать [документацию](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto), потому что такие базовые вещи обычно объясняются в самом начале.

Тем не менее, вот решение вашего вопроса.

```js
var eh = ace.edit("htmlEditor");
eh.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
eh.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
document.getElementById('htmlEditor').style.fontSize = '15px';

eh.getSession().on('change', function() {
  update();
})

function update() {
  var res = document.getElementById('result').contentWindow.document;
  res.open();
  res.write(eh.getValue());
  res.close();
}
update();

function download() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("drop-download");
  if (dropDown.style.display == "none") {
    dropDown.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function downloadHtmlFile() {
  var textToWrite = eh.getValue();
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "hhsh.html";

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  } else {
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
    // before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Oswald|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Yeseva+One&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#htmlEditor {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 43vh;
  width: 33.03%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#line {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -40% 0 0 31%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 501px;
}

#line2 {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -40% 33.3% 0 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 501px;
  float: right;
}

#line3 {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -40% 0% 0 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 501px;
  float: right;
}

#cssEditor {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 43vh;
  width: 33.03%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#jsEditor {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 43vh;
  width: 33.03%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#result {
  min-height: 440px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 79.6%;
}

#line4 {
  border-right: 4px solid #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: -26.8% 0% 0 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 414.5px;
  float: right;
}

#result-block {
  margin-top: -0.2%;
}

#title-of-textarea {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  background-color: #272822;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
}

#title-Html {
  padding: 0 0 0 1%;
  display: flex;
}

#title-css {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 2%;
  display: flex;
}

#title-js {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 2.5%;
  display: flex;
}

.mnu-code {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 2%;
}

.mnu-code li {
  padding-left: 5%;
}

#menu-code {
  width: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Arsenal', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#mnu-code {
  padding: 24% 0% 0 3%;
}

#drop-download {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  cursor: default;
}

#download-html::before {
  content: "\f13b";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#download-html {
  padding: 0% 0 0 5%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
}

#header-code {
  padding: 1% 0 1% 0;
  background-color: #1c1e19;
  display: flex;
}

#set {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#aside-block {
  width: 20%;
  height: 946px;
  background-color: #3b3d34;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content p {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.box-label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.save::before {
  content: "\f0c7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.download::before {
  content: "\f019";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#dropbtn-html {
  background-color: #272822;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
}

#dropbtn-css {
  background-color: #272822;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
}

.center-on-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0 !important;
  background-image: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

.select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2em;
  background: #2c3e50;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: .25em;
  margin: 1% 0% 5% 0;
  border: 1px solid #272822;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}


/* Arrow */

.select::after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  background: rgb(59, 61, 52);
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 2.4;
  -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
  -o-transition: .25s all ease;
  transition: .25s all ease;
  color: white;
}


/* Transition */

.select:hover::after {
  color: #f39c12;
}

#dropbtn {
  background-color: #272822;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 9000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 280%;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.language {
  padding: 6% 0 0 8%;
}

.dropdown-content #name-of-select1 {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content #name-of-select2 {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content-css {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9000;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 8%;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content-html {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9000;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 8%;
  display: none;
}

#title-js::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 4%;
  top: 5%;
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}

#title-css #dropbtn-css::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  left: 9%;
}

#title-Html #dropbtn-html::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  left: 9%;
}

.run-code::before {
  content: "\f144";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.change::before {
  content: "\f17a";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.box-text:before {
  content: "\f096";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#checkbox:checked+.box-text:before {
  content: "\f14a";
  color: #1e88e5;
  animation: checkanimate 200ms;
}

.box-label input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes checkanimate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal:400,400i&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js"></script>

<div id="aside-block">
  <div id="mnu-code">
    <label class="box-label">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked="" onclick="showTheme()">
  <span class="box-text">Темная тема</span>
 </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="header-code">
  <div id="menu-code">
    <ul class="mnu-code">
      <li class="run-code"> Проиграть</li>
      <li class="save"> Сохранить</li>
      <li class="change"> Поменять вид</li>
      <li class="download" onclick="download()">Скачать
        <div id="drop-download">
          <a id="download-html" onclick="downloadHtmlFile()">Скачать файл Html</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="htmlEditor"></div>
<div id="result-block">
  <iframe id="result" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div id="line4"></div>
</div>
```